# Expected type 'Number' got 'list[list]' instead

Tags: python, list, math

I have some nodes who transmit power and I have their positions in a list that I then use to calculate the power receiver from every node to the other so that's what I do:

```
Node_positions = [[0,100],[100,0],[0,0],[100,100]]
distances_Ascending = [[]] * len(list(itertools.combinations(Node_positions , 2)))
Counter = 0
for p0, p1 in itertools.combinations(Node_positions , 2):
    distances_Ascending[Counter] = (math.sqrt((p0[0] - p1[0]) ** 2 + (p0[1] - p1[1]) ** 2))
Counter += 1

Powers_Ascending = [[]] * len(list(itertools.combinations(Node_positions , 2)))

counter = 0
row = 0
next_no = sheet.nrows - 1
for elements in range(len(list(itertools.combinations(Node_positions , 2)))):
Powers_Ascending[elements] = 10 * (math.log10((sheet.cell_value(row, 0) * 1e-3))) - 20 * (
    math.log10((4 * math.pi * distances_Ascending[elements] * 2.4e9) / 3e8))
counter += 1
if counter == next_no:
    row += 1
    counter = 0
    next_no -= 1
```

Pycharm for python highlights this part:

```
(4 * math.pi * distances_Ascending[elements] * 2.4e9)
```

and says:

```
 Expected type 'Number' got 'list[list]' instead
```

What does that mean?Isn't distances_Ascending already a number which represents the distances between nodes and all the inside the log is a number already?

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me that distances_Ascending is a list of lists

```
>>> foo = [[]] * 3
[[], [], []]
```

so it is complaining because you are mulitiplying a list and a float.

From your code seems that you are incrementing the counter `Count` only after the end of the loop so you are only assigning to the first element of the list.
All the other elements are still lists from how the variable is initialised and you get the error on access.

The minimal change that you need to do is move the *Counter* variable inside the loop:

```
Node_positions = [[0,100],[100,0],[0,0],[100,100]]
distances_Ascending = [[]] * len(list(itertools.combinations(Node_positions , 2)))
# if you want to intialise the list it is better to do
# [0] * len(...your_calculations...)
# otherwise use the append() method of the list in the loop
Counter = 0

for p0, p1 in itertools.combinations(Node_positions , 2):
    distances_Ascending[Counter] = math.sqrt((p0[0] - p1[0]) ** 2 + (p0[1] - p1[1]) ** 2)
    Counter += 1 # <--- this was not properly indented, hence the error

Powers_Ascending = [[]] * len(list(itertools.combinations(Node_positions , 2)))
# same init comment as for distances_Ascending
counter = 0
row = 0
next_no = sheet.nrows - 1

for elements in range(len(list(itertools.combinations(Node_positions , 2)))):
    Powers_Ascending[elements] = 10 * (math.log10((sheet.cell_value(row, 0) * 1e-3))) - 20 * (math.log10((4 * math.pi * distances_Ascending[elements] * 2.4e9) / 3e8))
    # this part was also badly indented
    counter += 1      
    if counter == next_no:
        row += 1  
        counter = 0
        next_no -= 1
```

A few pointers for your coding:

- You don't really need to allocate lists, you can just use them in the loop by appending data to them.
- try not to change the type of data you are storing unless you ensure that the reader can easily follow up.
- try to use the standard python style conventions, it will help you a lot in coding with other people (see [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/))

Comment: but im saying `distances_Ascending[elements]` and this represents a number not a list of lists.

Comment: The definition of distances_Ascending generates a list of lists, this confused me since I was assuming that you were using it that way. The whole list allocation is not needed there since lists are dynamic, you can just assign the values in the loop. Now I see that the problem might be that you are incrementing the counter `Count` outside the loop, so you only set the first value as a number.

Comment: So what exactly should I change in my code so that the error goes away I don't quite get it.

Comment: It should be sufficient to put the counter inside the loop, let me update the answer with a snippet.